# Do some math over two columns of a .dat file and save results into a third column

Tags: python, csv, file-io

In python, having a .dat file with two columns, let say `[a1, a2, ... an]` at the first column and `[b1, b2, ... bn]` at the second one, how can I do some math in terms of the components of column1 and column2 and save the results the a new column3? For example, what is the easiest way to make the third column with the following components `[c1, c2, ... c3]` such that `cn = an + bn` ?

I have .dat file like

> a1    b1
>
> a2    b2
>
> a3    b3
>
> a4    b4

and I would like to make a new one as

> a1    b1   a1+a2
>
> a2    b2 a2+b2
>
> a3    b3 a3+b3
>
> a4    b4 a4+b4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do math on values, you have to turn them into numbers. For example:

```
with open(inpath) as infile, open(outpath, 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        a, b = map(float, line.split())
        total = a + b
        outfile.write('{} {} {}\n'.format(a, b, total))
```

Or:

```
import csv
with open(inpath) as infile, open(outpath, 'w') as out file:
    incsv = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=' ')
    outcsv = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in incsv:
        a, b = map(float, row)
        total = a + b
        outfile.writerow((a, b, total))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
f1=open(your_file,'r')
new_file=open("new_text.txt", 'w')
for line in f1:
    new_list=line.split()
    new_line=[new_list[0],new_list[1],str(int(new_list[0])+int(new_list[1]))]
    write_line= ' '.join(new_line)
    new_file.write("{} \n".format(write_line))
new_file.close()
```

Comment: This doesn't "do some math", it just concatenates strings.

Comment: @abarnert: I just answered what he wanted. He wanted to add two numbers of the each row and make a new column. Of course, I have forgotten to place int() or float if you mean that.

Comment: Yes, since that's the part he actually asked about, it's probably important to answer that part.

Comment: As a side note, because you never close the files, the output may end up empty or incomplete.

Comment: @abarnert: Yes, that's right but it was my assumption that he know that. I think, for his requirement, string or numbers won't matter. He just wants to add the numbers of each row and make the new column. But  yes, I sincerely appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

A convenient, flexible alternative using pandas that takes care of csv and everything in just four lines of code:

```
>>> import pandas as p
>>> df = p.read_csv('C:/code/test.dat', sep=' ', header=None)
>>> df
   0  1
0  3  4
1  5  6
2  7  8
3  1  2
>>> df[2] = df[0] + df[1]
>>> df
   0  1   2
0  3  4   7
1  5  6  11
2  7  8  15
3  1  2   3
>>> df.to_csv('C:/code/out.dat', sep=' ', header=None, index=False)
>>>
```